# XDocument get element that defines it's own namespace

Tags: c#, xml, windows-10-mobile

As question states. I have a xml document (below) and I need to get X_ScalarWebApi_DeviceInfo that defines namespace urn:schemas-sony-com:av. Unfortunately it results in an error: `{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. I'm mainly interested in ServiceList element, but it doesn't work as well. Platform - Windows 10 mobile.
Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">    
        <specVersion>
            <major>1</major>
            <minor>0</minor>
        </specVersion>    
        <device>
            <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:Basic:1</deviceType>
            <friendlyName>ILCE-6000</friendlyName>
            <manufacturer>Sony Corporation</manufacturer>
            <manufacturerURL>http://www.sony.net/</manufacturerURL>
            <modelDescription>SonyDigitalMediaServer</modelDescription>
            <modelName>SonyImagingDevice</modelName>
            <UDN>uuid:000000001000-1010-8000-62F1894EE7BE</UDN>    
            <serviceList>
               <service>
                   <serviceType>urn:schemas-sony-com:service:ScalarWebAPI:1</serviceType>
                   <serviceId>urn:schemas-sony-com:serviceId:ScalarWebAPI</serviceId>
                   <SCPDURL/>
                   <controlURL/>
                   <eventSubURL/>
               </service>
            </serviceList>
            <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo xmlns:av="urn:schemas-sony-com:av">
                <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_Version>1.0</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_Version>
                <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceList>
                    <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_Service>
                        <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceType>guide</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceType>
                        <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ActionList_URL>http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ActionList_URL>
                        <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_AccessType/>
                    </av:X_ScalarWebAPI_Service>
                    <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_Service>
                        <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceType>accessControl</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceType>
                        <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ActionList_URL>http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ActionList_URL>
                        <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_AccessType/>
                    </av:X_ScalarWebAPI_Service>
                    <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_Service>
                        <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceType>camera</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceType>
                        <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ActionList_URL>http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony</av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ActionList_URL>
                        <av:X_ScalarWebAPI_AccessType/>
                    </av:X_ScalarWebAPI_Service>
                </av:X_ScalarWebAPI_ServiceList>
            </av:X_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo>
        </device>
    </root>
```

Ah, the code:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml_text);
//var av = xDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();//.Attribute("xmlns");//
XNamespace av = "urn:schemas-sony-com:av";
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(av);
<XElement> api_list = (List<XElement>)xDoc.Element(av + "X_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo").Elements();
```

==EDIT==
Well, both solutions were ok, so I'm upvoting one and marking as answer the other :P
It was mentioned that the solution using only a 'local name' might cause false positive search results, so to be safe I'm using the first one. Thanks for help!

Comment: I forgot, to ad,, now it's in ;)
As you can see I tried many options I saw on the internet

Comment: Your `xDoc` have only one child element `<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">`, so call `.Element(av + "X_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo")` return `null`.

Comment: In future questions, try to clean up and format your xml a little. Visual studio does a good job.Those `-` on some lines are confusing.

Comment: Actually this is output of XML visualiser from VisualStudio, so no, it does not do a good job :P
I'll format it in a moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Element` only returns elements directly beneath the current node. You need the to specify the entire path (note there are multiple namespaces):

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0";
XNamespace av = "urn:schemas-sony-com:av";

var api_list = xDoc.Root.Element(ns + "device")
    .Element(av + "X_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo").Elements();
```

Comment: Are you sure about ns + "device"? Device is defined as <device> and has no namespace, so is it ok to add it in Element() call? I won't be able to check it today, but I'll check it as well as the other solution.

Comment: So what happens when there are two namespaces? Is it appended/overwritten? I can see that you're using only second namespace for descendant nodes that have different xmlns defined.

Comment: BUT if one needs to retrieve attribute of an element, should not apply the namespace!

Answer (score 3):

Using Xml Linq

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
XElement x_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "X_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo").FirstOrDefault();
XNamespace ns = x_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo.Name.Namespace;
```

Comment: Care to elaborate why? I like this solution, it's kinda... clear. And it would be best to assume that we don't know exact structure of the XML, but we may be sure that there's an element named uv:X_ScalarWebApi_DeviceInfo and of its structure (only descendants of it).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is indeed the Element or Elements methods only search the direct child elements. You can use Decendants() but you will get a collection, so you have to do First(expression) to het a single one.

But in the expression you can use .Name.LocalName to skip the whole namespace thing and look for just the name of the element.

For this question:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml_text);
XElement x_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo = doc.Descendants().First(x.Name.LocalName == "X_ScalarWebAPI_DeviceInfo");
```